# If I set private blockchain, will the dapp be private only?

Tags: private-blockchain, dapps

I have an ethereum private blockchain, and I need to build a web application, in which the content of blocks in private blockchain would be visible from anywhere after logging in on the web page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without evaluating the rational behind this, technically, I can tell: Yes it's possible. When you have a private chain, basically you're free to do what you want. For instance, if you have a number of nodes in a private group, you could isolate it completely through firewall rules and let your web application be the only access point from outside to it. User logins could sign the requests with their private key to get the access to your application.